# How do you append for example ?lang=en_US to the url based on a cookie containing country code?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, cookies, append

I have a code like this that extract the country code saved in the cookie.

```
        if (isset($_COOKIE['country'])) 
            {
                $country = $_COOKIE['country'];

                    $language = "eng";

                if ($country == "NO"){              
                    $language = "nor";
                    }                       
                }
            else
            {
            $language = "eng";
            }
```

Now I need to append the language from the `$supported_locales = array('en_US', 'no_NO');`

and append it to the url so it looks like this `http://localhost/site/test.php?lang=no_NO`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Location: http://localhost/site/test.php?lang='.$language);
```

or

```
echo '<script>location.href="http://localhost/site/test.php?lang='.$language.'"</script>';
```